# VPN over layer 2 setup

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, centos, mikrotik-routeros

Firstly, I'd like to mention, that I have only some IT knowledge, so I'm looking forward for you correcting me everytime I get something wrong :)

Also, I'm not expecting cmd-by-cmd solution, although if there's already a guide, please post a link here. I don't want to copy-paste, I want to learn something as well. For now, I'm not even sure what questions should I ask, so let me describe where I want to get.

So, I'd like to set up a VPN between my place, my parents' place, and my VPS. The idea is to have the VPS provide services like DHCP, DNS (with domain blacklisting), TFTP+SMB (for PXE), NTP, and basically everything I can come up with. I want to be able to RDP between computers.

So I thought of building layer 2 network.

But I'm not sure how to start. Should I use OpenVPN, or maybe there's an easier solution? My VPS is CentOS 7, but it has only one interface besides lo, and I'm going to need another interface for the local/internal network.

At home I have Mikrotik HAP AC2 router, and if I succeed with initial setup in my place, I'm going to buy one for my parents as well.

How do I start? How I make this secure?

Best regards,
Michal

**EDIT:** Maybe I should point out, that I want the VPN for "internal" traffic. To access the Internet, I want to use local routers.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a _good_ idea to bridge two networks like that. The only advantage of a L2 VPN _(not "VPN over L2")_ versus a regular L3 VPN would be working broadcasts and non-IP protocols, and I can only imagine it resulting in user confusion but no good practical use. Nearly all of your listed services would run fine over a L3 VPN.

Comment: I'm not sure as well, that's why I'm asking. Also, could you elaborate on user confusion and no good practical use? Generally, I want to have all the services configured on my VPS, not having to configure all the computers at all (all local config on routers), and being able to interact between computers as in every company I worked at...

Comment: Why do you want to become a veritable ISP for your parents? What's the point in such a fragile setup?

Comment: Firstly, I want to test it first on my place. Secondly, I want to learn. Thirdly, why you consider it a fragile setup?